# links on images in wysiwyg ckeditor

Tags: 7

I am working on a site using wysiwyg-7.x-2.2, media-7.x-2.0-alpha3 and ckeditor-4.3 as library
on drupal core 7.24.

The problem is:
If I put a link on an image in the wysiwyg editor, it doesn't get remembered. That means if I press "Disable Rich-Text" it hasn't been added and it will not get posted on save.
I can make a stand alone link and a add a stand alone image.
If I manually add the a tag to the image it CAN get saved.

Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the dev version of the media module

Comment: No, the problem is still relevant. https://drupal.org/node/2253433